# AudioFileOpenURL returns -43 on an existing file

Tags: iphone, core-audio

I have a step in my application where a user repeatedly hears three spoken digits.

If I leave this step running for a while (for certain undefined values of "while"), my debug logs show this (irrelevant log entries removed):

```
2010-03-01 13:44:21.283 iPhoneHearChk[1236:207] AudioFileOpenURL returned 0
 (for <file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/3A28F975-EAD5-4A5B-AFE6-FA1C6EE95732/iPhoneHearChk.app/5b3.ima4>)
2010-03-01 13:44:35.493 iPhoneHearChk[1236:207] AudioFileOpenURL returned 0
 (for <file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/3A28F975-EAD5-4A5B-AFE6-FA1C6EE95732/iPhoneHearChk.app/5b3.ima4>)
2010-03-01 13:45:17.916 iPhoneHearChk[1236:207] AudioFileOpenURL returned 0
 (for <file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/3A28F975-EAD5-4A5B-AFE6-FA1C6EE95732/iPhoneHearChk.app/5b3.ima4>)
2010-03-01 13:47:00.408 iPhoneHearChk[1236:207] AudioFileOpenURL returned -43
 (for <file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/3A28F975-EAD5-4A5B-AFE6-FA1C6EE95732/iPhoneHearChk.app/5b3.ima4>)
```

From what I've read, MacErrors.h defines -43 as fnErr, File Not Found. But clearly the file *does* exist, because I've successfully opened it before. What gives?

How I open the file:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: name ofType: type];
if (!soundFilePath) { NSLog(@"No path found for sound file %@.%@", name, type); }
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
rc = AudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef) fileURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &file);
```

where file is an AudioFileID instvar and name and type are NSString * parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you are running out of file handles?  Do you close the files you open after you are finished with them?

Comment: I had checked, but I will recheck. Certainly the call to AudioFileClose() is in the dealloc method, but I will check that the necessary object is indeed being released.

Comment: Indeed, an object holding an NSMutableArray holding the objects opening the files released the array, but not the items IN the array. Thus, none of the objects called AudioFileClose(). Thanks!